# nested form associated model getting autosaved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

My associated model gets autosaved. I would like this to happen only when those fields contains any values. Obviously `reject_if` is the way to go for this but I cannot get it to work. I've tried `:new_record?` together with passing in the Proc. But I suspect something else is wrong here as the `reject_posts` method below does not get called.

```
has_one :reservation, as: :reservable,  autosave: false,
                      class_name: Booking::Reservation
accepts_nested_attributes_for :reservation, reject_if: :reject_posts

def reject_posts(attributed)
  binding.pry
end
```

How would I go about to try to debug this?

Comment: Can you remove `autosave: false` and try if it gets called?

Comment: It doesn't get called then either.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about to try to debug this?

The first step is to make sure your flow is invoking the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method.

The simple check is to determine if your request console log sends the parameters as...

```
parameters: {
   "model" => {
     "reservation_attributes" => {...}
   }
}
```

If your params don't feature `_attributes`, your `fields_for` or flow are incorrect.

--

You should also make sure your `class_name` option passes a `string`:

```
has_one :reservation, as: :reservable, class_name: "Booking::Reservation"
```

---

I would personally do the following:

```
#app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :reservation, as: :reservable, class_name: "Booking::Reservation", inverse_of: :model
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reservation, reject_if: :all_blank?
end
```

The "rejection" is [not validation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-Validating+the+presence+of+a+parent+model). It just prevents the associated object from being passed to the nested model...

> You may also set a `:reject_if` proc to **silently ignore** any new record hashes if they fail to pass your criteria

I'd use validations on the other model (with `inverse_of`):

```
#app/models/reservation.rb
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model, inverse_of: :reservation
  validates :x, :y, :z, presence: true
end
```

--

If you wanted to reject based on specific attributes being blank, you should use:

```
#app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :reservation, as: :reservable, class_name: "Booking::Reservation"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reservation, reject_if: proc { |a| a['name'].blank? || a['title'].blank? }
end
```